# Is there a Google Sheet formula that will check if a Google Form is Accepting Responses?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I built a sheet that helps me manage my Trivia forms by clearing all input data and resetting validation. It works great, I'm happy with it, but now I want to update it to also Open and Close the Google Forms. I already have the script written, it works perfectly fine, but I'd like to have a cell underneath the Toggle that shows if the round is currently "Open" or "Closed" so I know if it needs to be toggled or not.

I couldn't find any formulas to directly access whether or not it's accepting responses, so I thought maybe I could use the XML formula to check the HTML for "This form is no longer accepting responses," but I'm getting a parse error on that. And if there's a way to check it directly, without having to peek at the HTML, that'd be ideal.

```
=IF(IMPORTXML(GOOGLEFORMURL,"//div[@class='freebirdFormviewerViewResponseConfirmationContent']")="This form is no longer accepting responses","Open","Closed")
```

Attached image shows the existing sheet - I just want to add a fourth row of buttons that, like the existing ones, show the current status.

[image: Existing Sheet]

Comment: Just realized I didn't have the Form URL in quotation marks - I fixed that, but it's still not working. I now get an "#N/A" in the box, and it shows an "Imported content is empty" error.

Comment: can you share that url?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jazSba1GqY0yIH6Srv-HXcUsH0d5cBJ5V2D9Z1uQt6w

Comment: You can also go to this Sheet to see what I'll be adding it to - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PFMrmgoAfvqxH6anfA-xdTaNyhuSJjDWHbsHexfyA8c

Answer (score 1):

if the form is closed then URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jazSba1GqY0yIH6Srv-HXcUsH0d5cBJ5V2D9Z1uQt6w
```

will autocorrect to:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jazSba1GqY0yIH6Srv-HXcUsH0d5cBJ5V2D9Z1uQt6w/closedform
```

and can be detected as:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)); "where Col1 contains 'docs-crp'"; )
```

where A1 is the URL of the form you shared

[image]

---

---

## UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

```
=REGEXMATCH(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'docs-crp'", ), "closedform")
```

(bound to the checkbox to force a refresh on demand)

[image]

then opening the form like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am at work right now but will test this in the full application when I get home tonight.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting "TRUE" regardless of whether the form is Open or Closed.

Comment: @SadBrontosaurus are you sure tho? I just tested it and works

Comment: I'm still not getting any success here. I've created a fresh Form and a fresh Sheet with open Editor access to anyone with the link.

Form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1E-LHVo4TLpdbT6pWFZ2MBaKTPc2UGl2G0l4rv2SecxE/edit#responses

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zn8u_4-mmtJ4CJshZ2tk_sltHKMeJuU3Jggv8qjefGI/edit#gid=0

I have tried using a) the code you shared, and b) the code shown in your pictures, as well as 1) long-form URL, and 2) shortened URL. I also added the Toggle button that I use, and assigned a working script. Clicking the button will open and close the form.